# Why egrep outputs two blank lines but "redirecting to file" produces actual text

Tags: grep

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.4 with stock grep version 3.4.

I find something I cannot explain, please help.

```
[/dev/pts/0(xterm-256color) 2023-04-04 10:28:01 ERR:0]
[chj @Ub20cppdev ~/test]
$ cat input3l.csv 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Comodo\",223743576,223920128
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Comodo\Dragon\",223743576,223920128
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Comodo\Dragon\dragon_s.dll",127097864,127098880

[/dev/pts/0(xterm-256color) 2023-04-04 10:28:07 ERR:0]
[chj @Ub20cppdev ~/test]
$ cat input3l.csv | egrep '(".+\\"),' 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Comodo\",223743576,223920128
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Comodo\Dragon\",223743576,223920128

[/dev/pts/0(xterm-256color) 2023-04-04 10:28:19 ERR:0]
[chj @Ub20cppdev ~/test]
$ cat input3l.csv | egrep '(".+\\"),.+' 



[/dev/pts/0(xterm-256color) 2023-04-04 10:28:33 ERR:0]
[chj @Ub20cppdev ~/test]
$ cat input3l.csv | egrep '(".+\\"),.+' > egrep1.txt

[/dev/pts/0(xterm-256color) 2023-04-04 10:28:43 ERR:0]
[chj @Ub20cppdev ~/test]
$ cat egrep1.txt 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Comodo\",223743576,223920128
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Comodo\Dragon\",223743576,223920128
```

[image]

Comment: I'd apply security updates to your system asap if you're still using 20.04.4 as you say & are on-line; as a fully-upgraded 20.04 system will currently report as [20.04.6](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/03/23/ubuntu-20-04-6-lts-released/) and your provided details imply you've not applied security fixes since [August 2022](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/09/01/ubuntu-20-04-5-lts-released/) if not before.  The links I provided are for ISO release dates, but installed systems got these updates week+ before the ISO release dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is almost certainly because of the interaction between color codes in the grep output and Windows-style (CRLF) line-endings in your input. You don't see the same when you redirect output, because the default egrep alias

```
$ alias egrep
alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
```

only colors the output when writing to a terminal. Compare for example:

```
$ printf '%s\r\n' 'foobar' | grep --color=always 'foo' | sed l
\033[01;31m\033[Kfoo\033[m\033[Kbar\r$
foobar
$
```

versus

```
$ printf '%s\r\n' 'foobar' | grep --color=always 'foo.*' | sed l
\033[01;31m\033[Kfoobar\r\033[m\033[K$

$
```

You can see that the trailing `.*` (or in your case, with `egrep` / `grep -E`, trailing `.+`) is capturing the carriage return character `\r` and emitting it *before* the closing ANSI color sequence `\033[m\033[K`, causing it to overtype the matched text `foo`.

See also [When piping grep after a curl request, regex works very strange](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1347113/when-piping-grep-after-a-curl-request-regex-works-very-strange)

Comment: Thank you. You just hit the nail on the head. After I save my csv with single `\n` as line separator, the weird behavior is gone.